# Adjective to describe a windshield that has its wiper blades turned on?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Raindrops fall on the [...] windshield. As soon they touch the
>   glass, they are gone.

I could only think of *moving windshield*. But I think it's not very suitable. Sounds as if the windshield is moving, not the wiper blades.

Comment: Would "guarded" or "protected" work?  It's a little tough since the windshield isn't actively participating in the process.

Comment: ...on the windshield with activated wipers.

Comment: If you want to do that, focus on the moving part: "The wipers move on the rain-slick windshield." (Or any of the variations on that.)

Comment: "Raindrops fall on the windshield, but with each swish of the wipers they are gone again."

Comment: This is getting perilously close to writing advice.

Comment: "wiped".  That's why they are called wipers.

Comment: [Shufflng](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shuffle) maybe? definition 2 or 3b.

Comment: Andrew and Josh.  I'm surprised at you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given in a comment, I'm not sure why you didn't give it as an answer, commentor?

The answer is simply **wiped**.

> We did a test in the lab with two windshields. One was being wiped, one was not being wiped. When rain fell on the wiped windshield, blah happened. When rain fell on the unwiped windshield, blah happened.

It's well worth noting that, wiper-systems development is a relatively H U G E industry in automotive circles.  (I believe it was said that *a billion dollars* was spent by VW the last time they worked on this system.)

Note that within that huge industry, with 100s of workers, 1000s of technical papers etc, it would be completely commonplace to speak of a "wiped windshield".

Sure, amongst non wiper-engineers, it would be less common - but so what? Chenmunka already gave the correct answer.

Regarding your posed sentence,

> Rain falls on the wiped windshield. As soon as they touch, they are gone.

Note however that this is more natural for us non-engineers:

> Rain falls on the windshield being wiped. As soon as they touch, they are gone.

Comment: Windshield wipers "swish", or, occasionally, "slap" or "flap".

Comment: Well they wipe, but they also do those things.  By all means, you can imagine the VW engineers saying "We did a test in the lab with two windshields. One was swishing, one was not swishing. When rain fell on the swishing windshield, blah happened. When rain fell on the unswisheder, blah happened."

Comment: I suspect that Opie is looking for phrasing a little less clinical than what VW engineers would use.

Answer (score 1):

All I can come up with is

**Raindrops fall on the windshield and, with the wipers on, they are soon gone.**